# Is this homebrew Copy spell balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, balance

A player created [this homebrew *copy* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/88751-copy):

> ## Copy
>
> *2nd-level conjuration*
>
> **Components**: V, S, M (an amount of coins equal in worth to the (unenchanted version of) the copied item)
>
> **Casting Time**: 1 minute
>
> When cast, the spell analyzes every part of a non-living item that fits in a cube of 5ft. squared and creates a near-perfect replica. The differences are not substantial enough to hinder the item's original function, but are substantial enough to distinguish it from the original (DC 10 perception). Any enchantments the item has are not carried over to the copy. The coins are immediately consumed at the start of the spell, but can be retrieved were the spell to be halted prematurely, in which case the unfinished copy disappears.

I am pretty sure it is not a good idea to allow it as it stands right now and am thinking about restricting it more.

I doubt that I am thinking about every possible repercussion.

With that said - I'd like some input about its viability, how to restrict it more or if it's hopelessly gamebreaking.

Comment: Hi Pascal, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange. Kindly take the [tour] and enjoy your stay!

Comment: Are you asking if the spell is balanced (e.g. against other spells of its level, and in the game in general)? Also, it's missing a range and duration.

Comment: How does it determine item's worth?

Answer (score 5):

This is too powerful for a level 2 spell.

Just compare it to *Fabricate*:

#### Pro Copy

- *Fabricate* is a level 4 spell, *Copy* is level 2
- *Fabricate* requires you to get your hands on materials you need to craft the object you're creating, *Copy* only requires you to spend coin.
- *Fabricate* has a casting time of 10 minutes, *Copy* requires only 1 minute
- *Fabricate* requires you to have proficiency to create items "requiring a high degree of craftsmanship"
- *Copy* allows for "plagiarism" (although the DC for the Perception check is low enough for the spell to be almost useless for this purpose (55% chance recognizing a copy even if not proficient in Perception and WIS mod +0)).

#### Pro Fabricate

- *Fabricate* can create larger non-metal objects
- *Fabricate* only requires you to get your hands on (="pay for") the raw materials, *Copy* also requires you to pay for the craftsmanship
- *Fabricate* has a range of 120ft, *Copy* has touch range.
- *Fabricate* does not require you to get your hands on an item to copy.

---

Comparing the benefits of *Fabricate*/*Copy* this spell should not be below level 4.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but as it stands, I can't be sure if you think the OP's proposed spell description *only* needs to be upgraded to 4th level in order to be balanced, with no other changes.

Comment: Is it really a significant advantage on the *copy* spell's part for it to have a 1 min. casting time *versus* the *fabricate* spell's 10 min. casting time? I mean, were the spell's author to change the *copy* spell's casting time 10 min. instead, would your evaluation change to have *copy* be a minimum of a 3rd-level spell?

Comment: Wouldn't already needing to have the thing you want be a __huge__ benefit of Fabricate, instead of the last item in the list?

Answer (score -5):

Personally, I don't think that is a good idea at all. That spell is incredibly overpowered for a 2nd level spell. Perhaps make it cost not just gold, but gems and time. That being said, the spell can lead to some very overpowered play and should be reserved for maybe a level 5 or 6 spell

Comment: Hi Jonnie K, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! When answering balance questions, it's very important that you justify your assessment --- you say it's "incredibly overpowered", but provide no reason to why that is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: JonnieK, please take the [tour] and visit the [help].  In particular, take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on an SE formatted site.  This isn't an internet forum.  You've got the beginning of a decent answer, but it needs a bit more support, as kviiri pointed out.